# Should I place <script> before or after the </html> closing tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Someone adviced me to put the *scripts* at the end of the documents.
Probably it makes the entire page load when script is not working (because it's at the end).

Now my question is: **should I include these scripts before `</html>` ending tag, or totally at the end of a document?** Or maybe it still should be contained in body?

Comment: Your question title is slightly misleading, making it seem like a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/436411/419956). Your actual question (so it seems) is "*can/should you place `<script/>`s before or after the `</html>` closing tag?*", right?

Comment: Scripts can be placed in head and/or body sections of the page. So I'd to put them before the ending body tag. Even better if you put them in separate file so that then they can be cached by the browser therefor improving loading speed (not to mention maintainability and reusability).

Comment: @Jeroen, well pointed. I agree with you that the OP has choosen a bad title. I have updated it and flagged it to reopen.

Comment: Not sure if it really needs to be reopened though. The duplicate-marking crossed me posting my comment. The marked duplicate's *title* ironically makes it look like it is not a duplicate, but it's close enough IMO as it requires ample reading of the dupe to see the answer to the question here as well. (If you cannot place it after </body>, it follows that you cannot place it after </html>, right?).

Answer (score 0):

You should place them before `</body>`

But this is a general statement and a simple answer - other issues may dictate other places to add scripts

Answer (score -3):

You can add it after `<body>`. It also helps the loading time of your page. The elements can be seen before the script(s) get executed.

Comment: Geez, bullies, take it easy! Comment corrections to help people instead of serially down-voting people who are trying to help. My original answer did not accurately reflect what I was thinking; my apologies for that.